# Select flat data into table format

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a schema similar to the following

```
id | year | month | amount ...
x  | 2011 | 12    | 312
x  | 2011 | 12    | 213
x  | 2012 | 1     | 123
x  | 2012 | 1     | 123
x  | 2012 | 2     | 123
...
```

I want to know if it would be possible (via mysql) to output something like

```
year | 1   | 2   | 3 | ....
2011 | 321 | 231 | ...
2012 | 246 | 123 | ...
```

So doing a `group by year, month`, `sum(amount)` and output one "row" per year with the individual months as the columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use a pivot table of sorts. If you are only dealing with months something like the below SQL should work for you. I only did the first three months but the rest are the same.

```
SELECT year, SUM(IF(month=1,amount,0)) As '1', SUM(IF(month=2,amount,0)) As '2', SUM(IF(month=3,amount,0)) As '3' FROM mytable GROUP BY year
```

Comment: Thanks, nice simple solution and seems fast enough.